# In a XUL Tree how does one format test in a cell RTL?

Tags: firefox, tree, xul, right-to-left

In XUL I have a tree (which is the XUL name for a DataGrid/Table)

```
<tree id="configTree" flex="1" seltype="single"          
          enableColumnDrag="true" context="configContext" hidecolumnpicker="true">
           <treecols>
    <treecol label="" editable="true"/>
    <splitter class="tree-splitter" />
    <treecol label="Term" flex="1"/>
    <splitter class="tree-splitter" />
    <treecol label="Counts" flex="1" />
  </treecols>
      <treechildren>
    <treeitem>
      <treerow>
      <treecell label=""/>
        <treecell label="מִמַּקֵּדָ֖ה"/>
        <treecell label="1"/>
      </treerow>
    </treeitem>
    <treeitem>
      <treerow>
        <treecell label=""/>
        <treecell label="צְא֖וּ כָל־אַנְשֵׁי־חַ֣יִ"/>
        <treecell label="2"/>
      </treerow>
    </treeitem>
  </treechildren>
</tree>
```

The test in the second columns are intended to be displayed RTL.

I've attempted to apply the css "direction:rtl", in a css file to various places.

```
treechildren::::-moz-tree-cell-text
{
  direction:rtl;
}
treechildren::::-moz-tree-cell
{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

I know the selectors are working as when I add `background-color: red;` as well as `direction:rtl` I can see the colors change in the cells, rows, and columns.

Currently displays like this:
[image: Screen shot of how it currently displays]

Comment: I unfortunately don't know your language.... Looks like it is RTL but the whole thing is left-aligned... Correct? And you want it right aligned because that would be the proper way to display it?

Comment: Yes most of the form is in English but this column needs to display text of different languages. In this example case Hebrew which needs to display RTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and as far as I understand the code, you can only set `direction` for either the whole tree or individual whole tree columns (see mentions of `moztreecell`/`moztreecelltext` in [`nsTreeBodyFrame.cpp`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/xul/tree/nsTreeBodyFrame.cpp)). Because essentially `<treecell>`s get converted to anonymous boxes by the tree builder, and only particular CSS rules are supported for those.

This means you cannot control the `direction` on a cell-level.

So, this might work (to a degree):

```
<treecol label="Term" flex="1" style="direction: rtl;"/>
```